# Can't find a new Jupyter kernel on gitpod

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, gitpod

I'm trying to install a new mysql kernel on Gitpod: https://pypi.org/project/mysql-kernel/
But visual studio code doesn't find the kernel

After installing the new jupyter kernel on gitpod.
Everything seems to be ok.

[image]

But visual studio code doesn't show the possibility to select a new jupyter kernel:

[image]

I would expect something like

[image]

([source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-kernel-management#_jupyter-kernels))

Answer (score 0):

You have to click "**Select Another Kernel...**" in:

[image]

to see these options:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution:
It seems that vs code on gitpod loads the jupyter kernel list on startup.
I added a .gitpod.yml to install the kernel before the workspace is started. It works to me

```
tasks:
- before: >
      pip install mysql_kernel;
      python -m mysql_kernel.install;
```

https://www.gitpod.io/docs/configure/workspaces/tasks